# SQLite archiving using Delphi

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-7, dbexpress

Is there any way in Delphi to archive all my sqlite3 tables in db A into db B(sqlite3)?

Background: I want to save away all of old data to db B and clean db A. The old data needs to be restored to the db A on demand.

Comment: Is there anything else in B, or can you simple copy the entire database?

Comment: No, database B will be say a temporary location for those old rec from database A.  Still A will be having fresh recs and on demand rec from B will be loaded to A.

Comment: What database driver are you using?

Comment: welcoming solutions with any driver. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SQLite C API has backup functions: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/backup_finish.html

If your current SQLite component(s) doesn't provide access, there's a unit to sqlite3.dll functions here: https://github.com/stijnsanders/TSQLite/blob/master/SQLite.pas#L546